# How can I change the preferred application for opening "fmp7://" URLs from FileMaker Pro Advanced to FileMaker Pro?

Tags: preferences

I have both FileMaker Pro and FileMaker Pro Advanced installed. Because the available licenses for the Advanced product are limited, I shouldn't use it unless necessary. But when neither application is running, my Mac will currently open any "fmp7://" URLs in FileMaker Pro Advanced. How do I change this so that FileMaker Pro is opened instead?

(There's no obvious configuration option for this in either application's Preferences window.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install the excellent [RCDefaultApp Preference Pane](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/Bundles.html#RCDefaultApp), which — amongst other things —  lets you declare the default handler for fmp7:// URLs.

Comment: That pref pane looks pretty old. Any info / experience on whether it works under OS X 10.6, 10.7, 10.8?

Comment: @gosmond seems to work fine for me under OS X 10.8.2!